# Is there a way to force iOS Safari to print in landscape?

Tags: css, ios, iphone

I am trying to enable users print a document in landscape from an iPhone web browser.

I have tried using `@media print{@page {size: landscape}}` which works fine on desktop Chrome but is having no effect in mobile Safari.

Other than using CSS to rotate pages 90 degrees, is there a way to tell mobile Safari to print in landscape?